# Asymptotic behavior of divergent $p$-series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, asymptotics, divergent-series

I am intertested in the asymptotic scaling behavior of the divergent $p$-series
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^p}
$$
for $0<p<1$, i.e., is there a closed-form sequence $a_n$ so that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^p}}{a_n}=c
$$
for some $0<c<\infty$? I am tempted to conjecture that $a_n=n^{1-p}$ (clearly works for $p=0$), but could not find a way to prove this.

Comment: Did you consider to look at an integral, given the monotonicity of $x^{-p}$?

Comment: You can use the [Euler Maclaurin Summation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula#Asymptotic_expansion_of_sums)